# Infinite sum with exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, laplace-transform, geometric-series

I am solving a question related to Laplace transform and I get the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-sn}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)^{n}.$$
The question asks me to show that this is equal to $\frac{e^{-s}}{1+s-e^{-s}}$. I recognise the possibility to use the geometric sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-sn}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)^{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(1+s)e^{s}}\right)^{n}\\&=\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{(1+s)e^{s}}}\\&=\frac{e^{s}(1+s)}{e^{s}(1+s)-1}.
\end{align}
By multiplying the fraction by $\frac{e^{-s}}{e^{-s}}$ I can get,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-sn}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)^{n}=\frac{1+s}{1+s-e^{-s}}.
$$
Therefore, my numerator is different to the numerator I am asked to show. Can someone explain to me where I went wrong?

**Edit**:

Based on the comment I solved it.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-sn}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)^{n}&=\frac{e^{-s}}{1+s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(1+s)e^{s}}\right)^{n}\\&=\frac{e^{-s}}{1+s}\cdot\frac{e^{s}(1+s)}{e^{s}(1+s)-1}.
\end{align}
Which can be simplified and again by multiplying by $\frac{e^{-s}}{e^{-s}}$ I do get,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-sn}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}\right)^{n}=\frac{e^{-s}}{1+s-e^{-s}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Sum starts from $n=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

It is IGP from $n=1$ to $\infty$. The sum is $\frac{r}{1-r}$, here $r=\frac{e^{-s}}{1+s}$.